# Formatting DATE in MySQL table when creating database?

Tags: mysql, database, error-handling, format

I keep getting an Error Code 1292 about "incorrect date value: '07/10/2020'" Whenever I run my script. I have been searching online on how to format date from the table, so when I build the database I can pull the date from it without having to format it from YYYY/MM/DD to MM/DD/YYYY. Is there a way to do this?

So for example, my table looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
. . . .
order_date DATE
. . . .
)
```

My INSERT INTO statement looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO orders (. . . order_date, . . .) VALUES
(. . .  '10/8/2010', . . .)
```

And this is the Error I receive (pasted below). I am guessing its because of the format of my date. I want it to display by Month-Day-Year but I am guessing I have to use something other than DATE to achieve that?

```
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '10/8/2010' for column 'order_date' at row 1
```

Also, can anyone explain what a 1452 Error means? I have never seen it before until now.

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`autotires`.`order_details`, CONSTRAINT `fk_order_detail_order` FOREIGN KEY (`order_num`) REFERENCES `customer_orders` (`order_num`))
```

This is the table.

```
CREATE TABLE order_details (
detail_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
order_num INT NOT NULL,
products_id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
quantity INT NOT NULL,
price DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_order_detail_order FOREIGN KEY (order_num) REFERENCES customer_orders (order_num),
CONSTRAINT fk_order_detail_products FOREIGN KEY (products_id) REFERENCES products (id) );

INSERT INTO order_details (detail_id, . . . price) VALUES
('1', . . . ),
( . . . '7.25');
```

Comment: "so when I build the database I can pull the date from it without having to format it from YYYY/MM/DD to MM/DD/YYYY" - no, always store dates using a date type, which requires YYYY-MM-DD.  if you want to format them when you select them, fine, use the date_format function for that

Comment: Don't ask two questions in one thread

Answer (score 1):

the default date format for mysql is 'YYYY-MM-DD'